# Log and read only last 10 minutes

Tags: powershell

I am begginer in Powershell and I have a problem with script.

I have a log and I need to send an email notification with an error. I would like to plan a task (TASK SCHEDULE) that will run my script regularly every ten minutes. This script verifies the last lines written in the last ten minutes. If the word ERROR is found, it will send an e-mail with this line where is the word ERROR.

My log:

```
2022-02-08 12:04:35,152 [105] ERROR RSeC.NET.RedundantHttpClient - No server found
2022-02-08 14:28:51,317 [4] DEBUG RSeC.NET.RSeC - Logging initialised
2022-02-08 14:28:53,835 [4] DEBUG RSeC.NET.JsonParser - Response binary data decoded. Size=424132
2022-02-08 14:29:20,494 [105] DEBUG RSeC.NET.RSeC - Logging initialised
2022-02-08 15:38:35,152 [105] ERROR RSeC.NET.RedundantHttpClient - No server found
2022-03-08 15:28:51,317 [4] DEBUG RSeC.NET.RSeC - Logging initialised
2022-03-08 15:28:53,835 [4] DEBUG RSeC.NET.JsonParser - Response binary data decoded. Size=424132
2022-03-08 15:39:20,494 [105] DEBUG RSeC.NET.RSeC - Logging initialised
2022-03-08 15:39:35,152 [105] ERROR RSeC.NET.RedundantHttpClient - No server found
```

My script :-(

```
$file = "C:\Soubory\esel.log"
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-50).Date

$cont = Get-Content -Path $file | Select-String -Pattern $date | Select-String "ERROR" | Measure-Object -line
   Foreach-Object {
     if ($cont -match "ERROR")
        {
        $kontent = Get-Content -Path $file | Select-String -Pattern $date | Select-String "ERROR" | Measure-Object -line
        Write-Host $cont
        }
     else 
        {
        #NOTING
        }   
                  }
```

Thank You for help

GILD

Comment: Could you explain what's wrong with your current script? What's failing? Where do you need help?

Comment: do you need to parse the time stamps for each line to find the "last 10 minutes" ... or can you just grab a certain number of lines from the end?

Comment: Is this a massive log file?  Some time ago I created a script where I avoided reading the entire log by reading enough bytes of data at the end of the log file to get an entire days logs, plus part of the day before, converted the bytes to string[], and then processed the strings.  But if it is a fairly small log file, then you might read the whole file into an array and work backwards from the last entry.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon my script doesn't work. I have no output.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey it is so big log with over 3k lines and every minutes are new lines.

Comment: @Darin Yes, it is a massive a log. Every minute a few lines are added to the end.
I tried invert-csv and specify the time format and the script still doesn't work for me. I'm drowning in it

Comment: @Gild, I don't have time to work on this till later today (Early morning here now).  But something you can do is right now is figure out what is the largest number of entries you could ever expect in 10 minutes.  Also, how long is the longest entry.  We can use this info as a starting point for how many bytes of data from the end of the file we need to extract.  After that, it is just an issue of extracting the bytes, converting to string[], and then extracting the data the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a csv without the header, and I can compare the first column like it's a date and time, so:

```
import-csv log -header time,message | 
  where { (get-date).AddMinutes(-10) -lt $_.time -and 
          $_.message -match 'error' }

time                message
----                -------
2022-03-09 10:11:35 152 [105] ERROR RSeC.NET.RedundantHttpClient - No server found
```

I would use the windows event log for easier filtering.

Comment: Thank You, It looks so easy but i have one problem. My output is flawed 
`Could not compare "03/10/2022 15:28:20" to "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.". E
rror: "Cannot convert value "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled." to type "System.D
ateTime". Error: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.""

`

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you.  It works with the example you gave.  Maybe there's some extra binary character at the beginning of your file.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71400212/log-and-read-only-last-10-minutes#comment126205399_71400212) gave you the answer in his comment.

Simply figure out the worst-case scenario to read the bottom number of lines of the file, where you can be certain the last ten minutes are in there.

Then do:

```
$maxLines       = 20  # just a guess here, but you can narrow the number of lines to read by trial and error
$lastTenMinutes = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10)
$errorLines     = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Soubory\esel.log' -Tail $maxLines | 
                  Where-Object { [datetime]($_ -split ',')[0] -gt $lastTenMinutes -and $_ -match 'ERROR' }

# test if there were error lines found
if (@($errorLines).Count) {
    # send your email alert.
    # If this email is in HTML format, use: $errorLines -join '<br>'
    # if the email is plain text, join with newlines: $errorLines -join [environment]::NewLine
    # for demo just output to console
    Write-Host ("Errors found:`r`n{0}" -f ($errorLines -join [environment]::NewLine))
}
else {
    Write-Host "No error lines found" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

<sup>On my Dutch locale, `[datetime]($_ -split ',')[0]` parses the date correctly, but on your machine you may have to use `[datetime]::ParseExact(($_ -split ',')[0], 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', $null)`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment on your question, "figure out what is the largest number of entries you could ever expect in 10 minutes".  When you have that number, change the "20" in line "$MinLinesToGet = 20" in the code below to that value.  Also, change the line "$MaxLengthOfALine = 100" so that it has the length of the longest line you expect to see.

If for some reason you need more than 10 minutes, change the value in the line "$MinutesOld = 10".

The code:

1. Uses ReadBytesFromFileEnd to read $ByteCount bytes from the end of $FilePath.
2. Uses ReadLinesFromFileEnd to read $MinLineCount of lines, each are expected to have less than $MaxLineLength, from the end of $FilePath.  In reality, it should read several lines more than we want - which is a good thing.
3. Uses "[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString" to convert the bytes to a string.  And then uses Split to make an array of strings that is saved in $Lines.
4. The UTF8 before GetString is a type of encoding, and is the most likely file encoding the log file is in, so you shouldn't have to change anything.  But, if there are problems, find the line "<## >" and remove the space when testing.  The code will then give the raw text lines that are being returned by ReadLinesFromFileEnd.  At that point, you can try the other encodings listed in the comment line above the GetString statement.  Most encoding have a character size of 1, but in some unlikely, or absurd case where your log file has a larger character size, then change the line "$CharSize = 1" as needed.
5. You didn't provide your regex you were using, so I built my own and used the switch statement to loop through all the lines that are returned by ReadLinesFromFileEnd.  I made the assumption that comma after the date WAS NOT part of a comma delimited line, but still part of the time stamp, and the numbers just afterwards is the milliseconds.  I don't know what the numbers in the brackets are, so I just gave it the name "Code".
6. Those lines older than 10 minutes are used to build a PSObject that you can use in later code.
7. The last 3 lines are an example using the returned log entries in a Write-Host statement.

This worked well in my testing, but never know till the code is actually tried in the real world.

```
function ReadBytesFromFileEnd{
   param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
      [string]$FilePath,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
      [int]$ByteCount
   )
   $fs = [IO.File]::OpenRead($FilePath)                           # Open file
   if($ByteCount -gt $fs.Length) {$ByteCount = $fs.Length}        # Prevent reading more bytes than exist
   $null = $fs.Seek(-$ByteCount, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::End)     # Position for reading
   $Return = new-object Byte[] $ByteCount                         # Define the buffer $Return
   $fs.Read($Return, 0, $ByteCount) | Out-Null                    # Fill the buffer
   $fs.Close()                                                    # Close the file
   return $Return
}

function ReadLinesFromFileEnd{
   param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
      [string]$FilePath,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
      [int]$MinLineCount,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
      [int]$MaxLineLength
   )
   $CharSize = 1
   [int]$ByteCount = 1.25 * ($MinLineCount + 1) * $MaxLineLength * $CharSize
   # Encoding Options: ASCII, BigEndianUnicode, Default, Unicode, UTF32, UTF7,UTF8
   $null, $Return = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString((ReadBytesFromFileEnd $FilePath $ByteCount)).Split(@("`n","`r"),[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
   return $Return
}

$MinLinesToGet = 20
$MaxLengthOfALine = 100
$MinutesOld = 10
$Lines = ReadLinesFromFileEnd 'C:\Soubory\esel.log' $MinLinesToGet $MaxLengthOfALine
<## >
$Lines
exit
#>

$Now = Get-Date
$RecentLogs = switch -Regex ($Lines) {
   '^(?<DateTime>\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d+)\s*\[(?<Code>\d+)\]\s*(?<Description>.*)$' {
      $DateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Matches.DateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff', $null)
      if ($Now.Subtract($DateTime).TotalMinutes -lt $MinutesOld) {
         New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            DateTime = $DateTime
            Code = $Matches.Code
            Description = $Matches.Description
         }
      }
      continue
   }
   Default {
      continue
   }
}

$RecentLogs | ForEach-Object {
   Write-Host "$($_.DateTime) [$($_.Code)] $($_.Description)"
}
```

**EDIT:**
You may want to check for lines that are not caught by the Regex.  If so, place the following lines between the `Default {` statement and the `coninue` statement.

```
      Write-Color "Regex failed to match: " -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewLine
      Write-Color "$_" -ForegroundColor Yellow
```